# Bound service from a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, sqlite

I want to save to a db info from an activity. Since its time consuming I want to to it from a bound service in a different thread. Searching the web and the tutorials shows how to run a started service from a thread and how to bind a service.
What I thought i can do is to create a new thread inside Service.onCreate() and declare a new IBinder implemntetion inside the Thread.run(). And return that IBinder in the Service.onBind().

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    IBinder mBinder;
    Public void onCreate(){
    New Thread(New Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            //declare MyBinder
            ..
            mBinder = new MyBinder();
    }}).start();
    }
    //in onBind return mBinder.
}
```

all calls to the binder should now happen inside the new thread. Am I correct. Is there an easier way?

Tnx

Comment: You just create binder on different thread.  And nothing more the thread ends right after creation

Comment: Why? There is still a reference to code inside the thread